# Passenger doesn't install with official Ubuntu Nginx package

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

So it looks like that I have some problems installing the recent passenger with official nginx packages. According to Passenger's official document here:

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#install_add_apt_repo

I have done everything it tells from 2.3.1. My system is Ubuntu 13.10 and is currently installed the  passenger Nginx via gem. Now I wish to change the service to using the official packages since I believe it does have better integration support, also along with better support with logrotate. So when I have executed the main command of installation:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-extras passenger
```

It spits error showing this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 nginx-extras : Depends: perl (>= 5.14.2-21+deb7u1) but 5.14.2-21build1 is to be installed
                Depends: libgd2-noxpm (>= 2.0.36~rc1~dfsg) but it is not installable or
                         libgd2-xpm (>= 2.0.36~rc1~dfsg) but it is not installable
                Recommends: passenger (< 4.0.34) but 1:4.0.33-1~wheezy1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I wonder why and how the dependency check is so strict to this degree. As it says I need packages for Debian but I am on Ubuntu so it is natural that the package names are slightly different. Can anyone make any solutions for this? Thanks very much.

Also, there is a side question: if this is successful, does Nginx automatically support IPv6?

Comment: what do you get when you run `apt-cache policy nginx-extras`

Comment: `nginx-extras:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.4.1-3ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
     1.4.1-3ubuntu1.1 0
        500 http://ubuntu.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/universe amd64 Packages
     1.4.1-3ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ubuntu.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages`

Comment: @wlicpsc could you share how your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list` looks like after fixed this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2.3.1 step 3, did you add the Ubuntu 13.10 APT repo, and not the Debian 6/7 APT repo? How does your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list look like?

Comment: Exactly like what the documentation has written in 2.3.2 Chapter. `# Ubuntu 13.10
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger saucy main
# Ubuntu 12.04
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger precise main
# Ubuntu 10.04
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger lucid main
# Debian 7
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger wheezy main
# Debian 6
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger squeeze main`

Comment: The documentation states that you're only supposed to add ONE of those lines, not all of them.

Comment: Charming, it worked! Thanks. One more question regarding the version of Ruby here. It seems during the installation it has installed the packages of Ruby 1.9.1 and 2.0, now I have 2.1.0 running on RVM, so what version of Ruby does Nginx use? Will there be any compatibility issues?

Comment: I think I have found something else in the doc, in 8.2.2 it specifies the ruby version of RVM in a separate site file, is that the standard way to do it or should I just change the path in the root config file?

Comment: It doesn't matter in which file you put passenger_ruby, as long as Nginx correctly reads your config option.